How to implement 2 different controllers in ROS2 Humble?
I'm trying to implement two different controllers in my project, but when running the RVIZ demonstration, only one controller starts (the second one says it couldn't find interfaces). However, if I run the demonstration with only one controller enabled, everything works fine. I investigated the issue and found that the problem lies in the fact that data from the .xarco files (which contain controller descriptions) is loaded into the variable hardware_interface::hardwareInfo::info_ only for one controller. How can I make sure that info_ is initialized for both controllers?
Here is code of my ros_controllers.yaml:
  ros__parameters:
    update_rate: 50  # Hz

    neck_controller:
      type: joint_trajectory_controller/JointTrajectoryController

    torso_group_controller:
      type: position_controllers/JointGroupPositionController

    torso_trajectory_controller:
      type: joint_trajectory_controller/JointTrajectoryController

    right_arm_group_controller:
      type: position_controllers/JointGroupPositionController

    right_arm_trajectory_controller:
      type: joint_trajectory_controller/JointTrajectoryController
      
    right_hand_controller:
      type: joint_trajectory_controller/JointTrajectoryController

    joint_state_broadcaster:
      type: joint_state_broadcaster/JointStateBroadcaster

    RobolCalibrationController:
      type: robol_calibration_controller/RobolCalibrationController

    RobolCoffeeMachineController:
      type: robol_coffee_machine_controller/RobolCoffeeMachineController
      

RobolCalibrationController:
  ros__parameters:
    command_interfaces:
      - calibration_command
    state_interfaces:
      - calibration_state


RobolCoffeeMachineController:
  ros__parameters:
    command_interfaces:
      - coffee_controller_command
    state_interfaces:
      - coffee_controller_state


neck_controller:
  ros__parameters:
    command_interfaces:
      - position
    state_interfaces:
      - position
    joints:
      - torso_neck_joint
      - neck_head_joint
    constraints:
      torso_neck_joint:
        goal: 0.03
      neck_head_joint:
        goal: 0.03


torso_group_controller:
  ros__parameters:
    joints:
      - leg_torso_joint


torso_trajectory_controller:
  ros__parameters:
    command_interfaces:
      - position
    state_interfaces:
      - position
    joints:
      - leg_torso_joint
    constraints:
      leg_torso_joint:
        goal: 0.03


right_arm_group_controller:
  ros__parameters:
    joints:
      - torso_right_shoulder_top_joint
      - right_shoulder_top_right_shoulder_bottom_joint
      - right_shoulder_bottom_right_forearm_joint
      - right_forearm_right_forearm_bottom_joint
      - right_forearm_bottom_right_wrist_joint
      - right_wrist_right_gripper_base_joint


right_arm_trajectory_controller:
  ros__parameters:
    command_interfaces:
      - position
    state_interfaces:
      - position
    joints:
      - torso_right_shoulder_top_joint
      - right_shoulder_top_right_shoulder_bottom_joint
      - right_shoulder_bottom_right_forearm_joint
      - right_forearm_right_forearm_bottom_joint
      - right_forearm_bottom_right_wrist_joint
      - right_wrist_right_gripper_base_joint
    constraints:
      torso_right_shoulder_top_joint:
        goal: 0.03
      right_shoulder_top_right_shoulder_bottom_joint:
        goal: 0.03
      right_shoulder_bottom_right_forearm_joint:
        goal: 0.03
      right_forearm_right_forearm_bottom_joint:
        goal: 0.03
      right_forearm_bottom_right_wrist_joint:
        goal: 0.03
      right_wrist_right_gripper_base_joint:
        goal: 0.03
      

right_hand_controller:
  ros__parameters:
    command_interfaces:
      - position
    state_interfaces:
      - position
    joints:
      - right_gripper_base_right_gripper_left_finger_joint ```

Here is code of the first driver:

``` coffee machine <?xml version="1.0"?>
<robot xmlns:xacro="http://www.ros.org/wiki/xacro">

    <xacro:macro name="robol_ros2_control_coffee" params="name initial_positions_file use_real_hardware:=^|false port baud">
        <xacro:property name="initial_positions" value="${load_yaml(initial_positions_file)['initial_positions']}" />

        <ros2_control name="${name}" type="system">
        <hardware>
            <xacro:if value="${use_real_hardware}">
                    <plugin>robol_coffee_machine_driver/robol_coffee_machine_driver::RobolCoffeeMachineDriver</plugin>
                    <param name="port">${port}</param>
                <param name="baud">${baud}</param>
                </xacro:if>
                <xacro:unless value="${use_real_hardware}">
                    <plugin>fake_components/GenericSystem</plugin>
                </xacro:unless>
            </hardware>
            <gpio name="coffee_controller"> 
                <command_interface name="coffee_controller_command"/>
                <state_interface name="coffee_controller_state"/>
            </gpio>
        </ros2_control>
    </xacro:macro>
</robot> ```

Here is the code of the second controller`s .xarco file:

``` <?xml version="1.0"?>
<robot xmlns:xacro="http://www.ros.org/wiki/xacro">

    <xacro:macro name="robol_ros2_control" params="name initial_positions_file use_real_hardware:=^|false port baud">
        <xacro:property name="initial_positions" value="${load_yaml(initial_positions_file)['initial_positions']}" />

        <ros2_control name="${name}" type="system">
        <hardware>
            <xacro:if value="${use_real_hardware}">
                    <plugin>robol_hardware_driver/RobolHardwareDriver</plugin>
                    <param name="port">${port}</param>
                <param name="baud">${baud}</param>
                </xacro:if>
                <xacro:unless value="${use_real_hardware}">
                <plugin>fake_components/GenericSystem</plugin>
            </xacro:unless>
        </hardware>
        <joint name="leg_torso_joint">
            <param name="initial_position">${initial_positions['leg_torso_joint']}</param>
                <command_interface name="position" />
                <state_interface name="position" />
            </joint>
            <joint name="torso_neck_joint">
                <param name="initial_position">${initial_positions['torso_neck_joint']}</param>
            <command_interface name="position" />
            <state_interface name="position" />
        </joint>
        <joint name="neck_head_joint">
            <param name="initial_position">${initial_positions['neck_head_joint']}</param>
                <command_interface name="position" />
                <state_interface name="position" />
            </joint>
            <joint name="torso_right_shoulder_top_joint">
                <param name="initial_position">${initial_positions['torso_right_shoulder_top_joint']}</param>
            <command_interface name="position" />
            <state_interface name="position" />
        </joint>
        <joint name="right_shoulder_top_right_shoulder_bottom_joint">
            <param name="initial_position">${initial_positions['right_shoulder_top_right_shoulder_bottom_joint']}</param>
                <command_interface name="position" />
                <state_interface name="position" />
            </joint>
            <joint name="right_shoulder_bottom_right_forearm_joint">
                <param name="initial_position">${initial_positions['right_shoulder_bottom_right_forearm_joint']}</param>
            <command_interface name="position" />
            <state_interface name="position" />
        </joint>
        <joint name="right_forearm_right_forearm_bottom_joint">
            <param name="initial_position">${initial_positions['right_forearm_right_forearm_bottom_joint']}</param>
                <command_interface name="position" />
                <state_interface name="position" />
            </joint>
            <joint name="right_forearm_bottom_right_wrist_joint">
                <param name="initial_position">${initial_positions['right_forearm_bottom_right_wrist_joint']}</param>
            <command_interface name="position" />
            <state_interface name="position" />
        </joint>
        <joint name="right_wrist_right_gripper_base_joint">
            <param name="initial_position">${initial_positions['right_wrist_right_gripper_base_joint']}</param>
                <command_interface name="position" />
                <state_interface name="position" />
            </joint>
            <joint name="right_gripper_base_right_gripper_left_finger_joint">
                <param name="initial_position">${initial_positions['right_gripper_base_right_gripper_left_finger_joint']}</param>
                <command_interface name="position" />
                <state_interface name="position" />
            </joint>
            <joint name="right_gripper_base_right_gripper_right_finger_joint">
                <param name="mimic">right_gripper_base_right_gripper_left_finger_joint</param>
                <param name="multiplier">1</param>
<command_interface name="position" />
                <state_interface name="position" />
            </joint>
            <gpio name="calibration">
                <command_interface name="calibration_command"/>
                <state_interface name="calibration_state"/>
            </gpio>
        </ros2_control>
    </xacro:macro>
</robot> ```

and here is the main URDF.xarco file:

    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<robot xmlns:xacro="http://www.ros.org/wiki/xacro" name="robol">
    <xacro:arg name="initial_positions_file" default="initial_positions.yaml" />
    <xacro:arg name="use_real_hardware" default="false" />
    <xacro:arg name="port" default="/dev/pts/0" />
    <xacro:arg name="baud" default="921600" />

    <xacro:include filename="$(find robol_urdf_model)/urdf/robol_urdf_model.urdf" />

    <xacro:include filename="robol.ros2_control.xacro" />
    <xacro:include filename="robol.ros2.control_coffee.xacro"/>

    <xacro:robol_ros2_control name="RobolSystem" initial_positions_file="$(arg initial_positions_file)" use_real_hardware="$(arg use_real_hardware)" port="$(arg port)" baud="$(arg baud)"/>
    <xacro:robol_ros2_control_coffee name="RobolCoffeeSystem" initial_positions_file="$(arg initial_positions_file)" use_real_hardware="$(arg use_real_hardware)" port="$(arg port)" baud="$(arg baud)"/> 
</robot>


Welcome to RSE. Could you please simplify your example to the two controllers causing the issue? And please add the console output from the controller_manager.
